# smoothing of isolated surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

I want to know when an isolated surface singularity can be smoothed, especially for log canonical isolated surface singularity. Is there any good reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking whether the germ of an isolated surface singularity can be realized as the fiber over the origin of the germ of a flat, finitely presented morphism from a threefold to a curve whose general fiber is smooth and such that the threefold is smooth away from the singular point of the fiber over the origin?

Comment: . . . Or are you asking about a resolution of singularities of surfaces (which goes back to Albanese and Abhyankar)?

Comment: Professor jason, your comment 1 is what I'm asking for.

Comment: Log canonical surface singularities have a classification, so you can probably check that. (See 3.3 in Kollár's Singularities of the Minimal Model Program). In general, a smoothable lc singularity is necessarily CM. This doesn't say anything in dimension 2, but it is a non-trivial fact in dimensions starting at 3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do know the classification for log canonical surface singularity. So is there any criteria for smoothing in dim 2?

Comment: I will add my two cents: if your singularities are *worse* than log canonical, they definitely do not always deform.  For instance, there is work of Pinkham characterizing when cones over canonical curves deform, i.e., roughly only when the canonical curve is a hyperplane section of a K3 surface (if memory serves).